# How to get related Model values with DB::raw(MAX) in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get related Model "User" values in this query.

```
$notify = Ask::select(DB::raw('MAX(id) As id'))
->where('q_id', $request->qid)
->whereNotIn('user_id', [auth()->id()] )
->groupBy('q_id','user_id')->get();
```

So, I added like below to get 'user.email':

```
$notify = Ask::with('user')->select(['user.email', DB::raw('MAX(id) As id')])
->where('q_id', $request->qid)
->whereNotIn('user_id', [auth()->id()] )
->groupBy('q_id','user_id')->get();
```

Also, I tried:

```
$notify = Ask::with('user')->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) As id, user.email'))
->where('q_id', $request->qid)
->whereNotIn('user_id', [auth()->id()] )
->groupBy('q_id','user_id')->get();
```

And both get error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found`.
So, what should I do to get User model's values?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

** SOLVED **

```
$notify = Ask::with('user')->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) As id, user_id'))
```

And, it worked.